# Rails load selective contents into view using jquery load function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-load

Recently, I've found this [template from codyhouse](https://codyhouse.co/gem/animated-page-transition-2/) which I decided to play with it a little in a sample rails app.

Looking into the code, I found that the page transition from the side navigation bar is happening via jquery load function.

From what I understand, whenever view, say `user/show`, gets loaded in rails, the contents written in the specified url, which in this case would be the contents in my `user/show.html.erb` file, gets embedded in the `application.html.erb` file.

As this is the case, I was wondering if there would be a way to "swap" contents being embedded into the `application.html.erb` file perhaps via jquery load function. For instance, without having to reload the whole view, replace the `user/show.html.erb` contents loaded in the page with the contents of `user/signup.html.erb`. Or is it not possible as it deviates from the concept of the MVC model?

Comment: This is pretty much what [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) (part of Rails 4 and 5) does for you behind the scene. You can customize the behavior, but in general you should see few page reloads on a Rails app.

Comment: @taglia Ah ha! Thank you!